# RecyclerView lags in scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with cardview in it. Also having imageview, textview. I am decoding my images using Base64 decoding scheme and displaying images within the cardview.It loads the images but producing the lag effect

onBindViewHolder code

```
holder.iv_contestant_image.setImageBitmap(new ProcessImage().getBitmage(contestant.getContestant_image()));
```

ProcessImage code

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(strBitmap, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
return decodedByte;
```

Is something wrong am I doing ?

Comment: Try to use some libraries for Image Loading.

Answer (score 1):

you can use any image loading libraries. Some of libraries are [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)

Comment: I have seen Picassso but it do not load Bitmap images

Comment: Are you trying to load from url?

Comment: No, I get a string to which I convert into byte array and do the Base64 decoding and load the image

Comment: No need to do all these thing just pass your url it will do all things for you.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe decoding process is not instant depending on the size of the bitmap. So, try perform decoding bitmap with AsyncTask

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private String base64Img;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView, String base64Img) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        this.base64Img = base64Img;
    }


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64Img, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        return decodedByte;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            imageViewReference.get().setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Inside onBindViewHolder

```
new BitmapWorkerTask(holder.iv_contestant_image, stringBitmap).execute();
```

Comment: This might cause an NPE. If the decoding is slower than the scrolling speed. Because of the View destroy and recreation.

Comment: I will try this, and the same problem I do have for cardView which having seekbar, the sliding effect lags what will be the reason for it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can implement lazy image loading in your recycle view for fix this issue. http://blogs.innovationm.com/lazy-loading-and-memory-management-of-images-in-listview-in-android/